# AucTex: Output PDF Buffer Location

Tags: latex, buffers, auctex

When hitting `C-c C-a` to display a PDF, the buffer opens automatically below the TeX source code. How can I force it to open on the right side?

I am currently using [`shackle`](https://depp.brause.cc/shackle/) to manually control the location of buffers, but the line below does not work (this `shackle` setup has been tested with other buffers):

```
(use-package shackle
  :ensure t
  :custom
  (shackle-rules '(("^.*\\.pdf$" :regexp t :align 'right :size 0.25 :select t)
           ))
  (shackle-default-rule nil)
  )

(shackle-mode 1)
```

Surprisingly, I am able to control the relative size of the buffer (`:size`) as long as I specify `` :align `below `` (which also indicates the regular expression is being correctly matched).

Is this perhaps related to the `TeX-view` function?

Comment: if you are using `latex-preview-pane-mode`, the window is split verticaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to my own question.

The package `shackle` fiddles with `pop-buffer`, which in turn is used by `TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view`, one of the functions being called when running AucTex's `TeX-command-run-all` (bind to `C-c C-a`). By avoiding `shackle` altogether for `*.pdf` buffers one can modify the standard splitting behaviour of `pop-buffer` as follows (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167246/emacs-open-buffer-in-vertical-split-by-default)):

```lisp
(setq
   split-width-threshold 80
   split-height-threshold nil)
```

To further control the width of the output buffer one can extend `TeX-command-run-all` (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows)):

```lisp
(defun reduce-this-window-width ()
  "Reduce current window based on the the width of the other window."
  (shrink-window-horizontally (/ (window-width (next-window)) 5)))

(defun my-TeX-command-run-all (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (TeX-command-run-all arg)
  (reduce-this-window-width)
  (pdf-view-auto-slice-minor-mode)
  (pdf-view-fit-width-to-window)
  )

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-a") #'my-TeX-command-run-all)))
```

where `pdf-view-auto-slice-minor-mode` and `pdf-view-fit-width-to-window` can be used to, respectively, slice the margins and fit the `*.pdf` to the buffer width. The value `5` can be tuned according to personal preference.